# How to loop data(select options) query into database, including each query in different rows under the same database

Tags: php, laravel, loops, foreach

Okay this is my problem, i have a form with select options with a maximum of 36 options, and when i click submit, i want all the options selected to be sent to an mysql server using loop method, can anyone suggest ways to help?

I have the done something, but i keep getting undefined variable "l" when i submit the options.

```
public function save_location(Request $request)
{

    foreach($l as $location){
        $s = new SurveyLocation();
        $s->survey_id = $survey_id;
        $s->location = $l;
        $s->save();
    }
}
```

i expect the code to send the query as a lop to the database without any errors

Comment: maybe you must be use `$l = $request->some_property` before foreach

Comment: At the moment you are looping over the variable `$l` and storing each record in the variable `$location`. I think you want the other way around. You also need to define `$location = $request->input('location');` before your loop.

Comment: PS remember to name your html element as an array, e.g. `<select multiple name="location[]">`

Comment: `$l` does not exist in the context. You need to get it out of the request. In your loop, you're trying to assign `$l`, not the `$location` of each `$l`

Answer (score 1):

use this code:

```
foreach($request->location as $l ){
    $s = new SurveyLocation();
    $s->survey_id = $survey_id;
    $s->location = $l;
    $s->save();
}
```